# Java Upcast versus Downcast

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code

```
    class X{} 
class Y extends X{} 
class Z extends X{} 

public class RunTimeCastDemo{ 
 public static void main(String args[]){ 
 X x = new X(); 
 Y y = new Y(); 
 Z z = new Z(); 


 X x1 = y; // compiles ok (y is subclass of X), upcast 
 X x2 = z; // compiles ok (z is subclass of X), upcast
```

The code above was given to me in a lecture. I know that X is the base class of both Y and Z. x is a reference to an X type object, y is a reference to an Y type object, and z is a reference to a Z type object. The part that is confusing me is the last two lines of the code. From my understanding, the reference x1 of type X is assigned the same reference as y which is type Y. Since x1 is assigned to the same reference as y, that means it goes from type X to Y which would be downcasting. Am I reading the code wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your class hierarchy

```
Object
  |
  X
 / \
Y   Z
```

> From my understanding, the reference x1 of type X is assigned the same
>   reference as y which is type Y. Since x1 is assigned to the same
>   reference as y, that means it goes from type X to Y which would be
>   downcasting. Am I reading the code wrong?

```
X x1 = y; // compiles ok (y is subclass of X), upcast
```

You're assigning `y` to `x1`. You're assigning a reference of type `Y` to a reference of type `X`. Looking at the hierarchy, you're going upwards, thus `upcast`.

Comment: I like the way you visually explain this one.

Answer (score 3):

When an instance of type `Y` or `Z` (subclass) is treated as the base type (superclass) `X` this is an upcast.

Upcasts are implicit(hidden) and cause a derived type to be treated as a super type.

This is an example of an upcast:

```
X x1 = y;
```

The cast is implicit (hidden) but could be thought of as:

```
X x1 = (X) y;
```

A downcast is from a super type to a derived type.  So to downcast `x1` to the type `Y` :

```
X x1 = y;
Y y1 = (Y) x1;
```

Downcasts are not implicit and must be explicitly declared.  They create the potential for a `ClassCastException` if the instance we are casting is not of the type we are casting to.

Comment: What would be the proper way of reading "X x1 = y;"? I don't think I interpreted it right.

Comment: I would read it as an instance of `Y` named `y` is being assigned to `x1` which of the type `X`.  During the assignment an implicit (hidden) upcast occurs from type `Y` to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Y extends X means that the objects you create with `new Y()` will be of type Y and consequently of type X. Because one derives from the other and X is the super class, any object that is of type Y is also of type X.

For example all classes in java derive from the Object class, hence, a String is a string and also an Object.

Answer (score 0):

It is upcasting, because you have an instance of type Y which is referenced by a variable of type X, and X is ´up´ (above) in the class hierarchy.